# Detect Internet Explorer 9 in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to detect from server-side in an MVC4 Website the Internet Explorer 9, but
 Request.Browser.Browser returns Mozilla and Request.Browser.MajorVersion returns 0.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to ask what should be the obvious question: why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("MSIE 9.0"))
{

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I get "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) "

Comment: @Patrick `rv:11.0` is indicating that you're using IE 11. (Taken from [Understanding user-agent strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms537503.aspx).)

Comment: I'm testing my website in a compatible of IE9 from the IE11

Comment: @Patrick Then it's still not sending the `MSIE 9.0` portion of the user-agent.  You could use [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/) to send a specific user-agent for a request.  That would allow you to test whatever you're trying to do.  However, if you want to know more about why IE11 shows up as Mozilla, you'll find [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx) interesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Request.Browser
```

You have all sorts of browser data available on this object, see this [Browser Capabilities MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx) for more details.